# How to get JS array value from nth value of form dropdown?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following dropdown option in a form:

```
<select id="candidates">
    <option value="select">Pick one</option>
    <option value="Candidate 1">Candidate 1</option>
    <option value="Candidate 2">Candidate 2</option>
    <option value="Candidate 3">Candidate 3</option>
</select>
```

And I also have the following array defined:

```
const selectedcandidate = ["/image1.png", "/image2.png", "/image3.png"];
```

I'm trying to declare a variable that will contain the image file of the corresponding candidate that was selected from the dropdown:

```
finalselectedcandidate = selectedcandidate[candidates[n]];
```

However, the code above doesn't work. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please share a full snippet, where is n set, what are you setting candiates to?

Comment: I apologize but I'm not understanding your question. After a user selects the dropdown option, I'm trying to get the corresponding image and store it in a variable to display in another page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask specially the "Help others reproduce the problem" section. We don't know how your code looks hence we don't know where is your actual problem. We are not here to write full code to a question like Copilot, but to help you with the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but maybe this what you are looking for?

```
<select id="candidates" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="select">Pick one</option>
    <option value="0">Candidate 1</option>
    <option value="1">Candidate 2</option>
    <option value="2">Candidate 3</option>
</select>
```

With this function should do the trick

```
function myFunction(){
    const selectedcandidate = ["/image1.png", "/image2.png", "/image3.png"];
  
  let e = document.getElementById("candidates");
  let value = e.value;
  
  if(selectedcandidate[value] !== undefined){
    alert(selectedcandidate[value]);
  }
  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this is to use the `onChange` event. Also you will need some way to relate the candidates to the pictures. One way to do that is to use a JS object with the select values as keys.

```js
const candidates = {
  "Candidate 1": "image1.png",
  "Candidate 2": "image2.png",
  "Candidate 3": "image3.png"
}

function handleOnChange(selectElement){
  const selectedCandidate = selectElement.value;
  const selectedImage = candidates[selectedCandidate];
  console.log(`Selected image: ${selectedImage ?? "No image selected"}`);
}
```

```html
<select id="candidates" onchange="handleOnChange(this)">
    <option value="select">Pick one</option>
    <option value="Candidate 1">Candidate 1</option>
    <option value="Candidate 2">Candidate 2</option>
    <option value="Candidate 3">Candidate 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build it into your app as follows:

```js
const selectedcandidate = ["/image1.png", "/image2.png", "/image3.png"];

$('#candidates').on('change', function() {
    const val = this.value,
          suffix = val !== 'select' ? +val.split(' ')[1] : null,
          index = suffix ? suffix - 1 : suffix,
          img = suffix ? selectedcandidate[index] : index;
          
    console.log( val, suffix, index, img );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="candidates">
    <option value="select">Pick one</option>
    <option value="Candidate 1">Candidate 1</option>
    <option value="Candidate 2">Candidate 2</option>
    <option value="Candidate 3">Candidate 3</option>
</select>
```